# Is there way to try-catch static properties in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose that there is a code (error occurs on the server side):

```
public class Foo{

    private static readonly Int32 MyProp = 10 / Convert.ToInt32("0");

    public Foo() {
        /// some initialization
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you wanting somewhere (anywhere) that you can write some code to catch the error (such as a static constructor) or are you wanting to (specifically) catch the exception from somewhere *outside* of the `Foo` class?

Comment: 1) You can write a static function whose result you assign to the property. That function can use whichever exception handling it likes. 2) You could use a static field of type `Lazy<T>`, that way it'll only throw when you actually access the value. 3) Why are your static properties even throwing exceptions? That's a rather dubious idea. Consider using a dependency-injecting a singleton instead.

Answer (score 5):

Move the initialization from *field* into into *static constructor*:

```
  public class Foo {
    private static readonly Int32 MyProp;

    public Foo() {
        /// some initialization
    }

    // static constructor for static initialization
    static Foo() {
      try {
        MyProp = 10 / Convert.ToInt32("0");
      }
      catch (SomeException e) {
        ...
      }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Since the presence of a static constructor affects when static initialization happens and causes a slowdown to static field access even long after initialization, a static function used as field initializer might be preferable in some scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

What if you use static property.. ?

```
private static int MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            return 10 / Convert.ToInt32("0");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The question states that "error occurs on the server side", so *initialization* (the server is called *once*)
solution could well have less overhead than *property* one. A compromise solution is to use `Lazy<T>`